# What is a word that means "to make sane"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Hypothetical: there is `something` that is pretty convoluted or difficult to understand. It is described as insane.

What is the verb that would be used to describe what someone would do to make the `something` sane?

Comment: Your question is confusing and unclear. Please edit it to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Why, *sanitize*, of course.

Comment: @DanBron Oh come on! "There ain't no sanity clause."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Rationalize***, to make it rational, to apply logic or reason to something.

You can also consider ***clarify***, to make something easy to understand.

Comment: Actually, the primary meaning of *rationalize* is not to make something rational, but to make it **appear** rational.

Comment: "jsw29 I'd agree, though M-W lists both senses together, and I'd say OLD disagrees.

Answer (score 1):

Rehabilitate?  Has both the feel of "fix" and institutionalization...

Answer (score 1):

***Sanify*** is an English word, albeit rare, which means to make something healthy/healthful. ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanify), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sanify))

I think it can be useful as an alternative to ***sanitize*** which is usually interpreted as making something clean ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanitize), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sanitize)), although both have the same root in the Latin *sanus* (health).

Comment: Although in the OP's particular example, ***clarify*** or ***sanitize*** can both work, in terms of making your `something` clear or clean.

Answer (score 0):

"Untangle" and the buzzword "unpack" both have the sense of *making order out of chaos*, which is a phrase for the meaning you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Sanitize.

The term that refers to making something sanitary should be "sanitarize", right?

Comment: I would have said "saneitize".

Answer (score -1):

When you **delineate** something, others may **ascertain** how to understand it.

Source: [Kids in the Hall](https://archive.nerdist.com/ascertain-the-delineation-with-the-kids-in-the-hall/)

*Side Note: although this answer does include a humorous reference, it is still intended as a valid answer to the question.*

The definition of "delineate" is to describe or portray (something) precisely.